# Using a permutation table for simplex noise without storing it

Tags: maps, procedural-generation, random

Generating [Simplex noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise) requires a permutation table for randomisation (e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18801877/931303) or [this example](https://code.google.com/p/battlestar-tux/source/browse/procedural/simplexnoise.py)).

In some applications, we need to persist the state of the permutation table. This can be done by creating the table, e.g. using

```
def permutation_table(seed):
    table_size = 2**10  # arbitrary for this question
    l = range(1, table_size + 1) 

    random.seed(seed) # ensures the same shuffle for a given seed
    random.shuffle(l)
    return l + l  # see shared link why l + l; is a detail
```

and storing it.

Can we avoid storing the full table by generating the required elements every time they are required?

Specifically, currently I store the table and call it using `table[i]` (table is a **list**). Can I avoid storing it by having a **function** that computes the element `i`, e.g. `get_table_element(seed, i)`.

I'm aware that [cryptography already solved this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910361/931303) using block cyphers, however, I found it too complex to go deep and implement a block cypher.

Does anyone knows a simple implementation of a block cypher to this problem?

Comment: what is the problem of storing it in a table and looking it up ?

Comment: As far as understand, memory allocation. E.g. in random map generation, a table can be large. This and the fact that one may need more than one table for a given map, makes this procedure interesting.

Comment: Looking at the code on http://www.6by9.net/simplex-noise-for-c-and-python/ it looks like the tables are under 1 kbyte. Do you really need one table for each map? I thought the permutation table is shared among all maps. The compiled code is probably more than 1k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using very large table sizes, I would suggest just using a hash function.  The permutation table is just a kind of pre-calculated hash function anyway.  I don't believe the permutation property (i.e. that there are no collisions within the table size) is required for good simplex noise.

Some hash functions that could do the job are [listed here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html).  I've used the first one on that page, Thomas Wang's 32-bit integer hash, quite a bit.  I copied its source code below:

```
uint32_t hash(uint32_t a)
{
    a = (a ^ 61) ^ (a >> 16);
    a = a + (a << 3);
    a = a ^ (a >> 4);
    a = a * 0x27d4eb2d;
    a = a ^ (a >> 15);
    return a;
}
```

This might even be faster than looking up a value from a large table, if the memory access takes longer than the 10 math operations in the above function.  I haven't benchmarked this though.  Probably the table stays in cache pretty well when you're generating many noise values.

Also, you can easily incorporate a per-map seed by changing the values passed to the hash function.  For instance you can pass `(seed * mapHeight + y) * mapWidth + x` to generate a different value for each xy coordinate in each map.

Comment: I confirm that being or not permutation table is irrelevant. This simplifies the job from the start. Thanks.